# Number of elements in the cyclotomic $F$ class.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, symmetric-groups, roots-of-unity, automorphism-group

Let $F$ be a  finite field with $p^n$ elements with prime $p > 5$ and $G = S_5$ the symmetric group. Let $l$ be the l.c.m. of the orders of the elements of G and $\theta$ be the primitive $l^{th}$ root of unity over $F$. Define the multiplicative group $$T = \{k\ | \theta \to \theta^k  \ \text{  is automorphism of} \ F(\theta) \ \text{over} \ F\}$$ Then what is $|T|$?

Comment: Sorry about the (now deleted) outburst. Best of luck with this. By Galois theory of finite fields $T$ is the subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_\ell^*$ generated by Frobenius, that is, the residue class of $p^n$ modulo $\ell$. Because $a^4\equiv1\pmod{60}$ for all $a$ coprime to $60$, we can say right away, that there are at most four automorphisms in $T$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.