# No of elements in a subgroup of the Galois group.

Tags: finite-fields, automorphism-group, frobenius-groups

Let $F$ be a  finite field with $p^n$ elements with prime $p > 5$ and $G = S_5$ the symmetric group. Let $l = 60$ be the l.c.m. of the orders of the elements of G and $\theta$ be the primitive $l^{th}$ root of unity over $F$. Define the multiplicative group $$T = \{k\ | \theta \to \theta^k  \ \text{  is automorphism of} \ F(\theta) \ \text{over} \ F\}$$ Then what is $|T|$?

What I know is $Gal(F(\theta), F)$ is a cyclic group and as $(60, p) = 1$ image of  $Gal(F(\theta), F)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{60}^*$, mutiplicative group, is $p^n\pmod{ 60}$. So same thing holds for $k$ also. How to think? Please elaborate.

Comment: Why did you delete [the previous version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2680394/11619)?

Comment: Because i have smplified my question

Comment: And editing the earlier question was not an option because.....?

Comment: Because i think many people were not going through it as they had already seen it once. I may be wrong. So.